# How do i output a csv file in a table format? (C)

Tags: c, csv, datatable, output

im relatively new to C and i'd like to know how to show the output of a csv file in a table.

Some names are way bigger than others and it gets difficult to comprehend in the output. Is there a way to output it in columns?

this is an example of the lines in the csv file:

```
code; name; state; owner; latitude; longitude; kind; size; difficulty; terrain; status; hidden_date; founds; not_founds; favourites; altitude

GCQC0V;Lenda Do Galo de Barcelos;BRAGA;ar-my;41.5282;-8.622067;MULTI;SMALL;2;1.5;AVAILABLE;2005/08/29;361;21;4;17

GCZP2A;Chromite - FeOCr2O3 - DP/EC5;BRAGANCA;danieloliveira;41.802433;-6.88395;EARTHCACHE;NOT_CHOSEN;1;1.5;AVAILABLE;2006/12/05;62;2;2;838

GCMAM8;A Lagoa [Obidos];LEIRIA;paulohercules;39.390417;-9.225283;TRADITIONAL;REGULAR;2;2;AVAILABLE;2004/12/22;703;9;3;19
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input.h"

int main() {
    Cache cache;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("caches_all.csv", "r");

    char myString[1000];
    fgets(myString, 1000, fp);

    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets(myString, 1000, fp)) {
            sscanf(myString, "%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%lf;%lf;%[^;];%[^;];%lf;%lf;%[^;];%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%lf",
                cache.code, cache.name, cache.state, cache.owner, &cache.latitude, &cache.longitude,
                cache.kind, cache.size, &cache.difficulty, &cache.terrain, cache.status,
                cache.hidden_date, &cache.founds, &cache.not_founds, &cache.favorites, &cache.altitude);

            printf("%s %s %s %s %.6lf %.6lf %s %s %.1lf %.1lf %s %s %d %d %d %.0lf\n",
                cache.code, cache.name, cache.state, cache.owner, cache.latitude, cache.longitude,
                cache.kind, cache.size, cache.difficulty, cache.terrain, cache.status,
                cache.hidden_date, cache.founds, cache.not_founds, cache.favorites, cache.altitude);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Not able to open the file.");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

this is the header with the struct:

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H

typedef struct cache {
    char code[500];
    char name[500];
    char state[500];
    char owner[500];
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    char kind[500];
    char size[500];
    double difficulty;
    double terrain;
    char status[500];
    char hidden_date[500];
    int founds;
    int not_founds;
    int favorites;
    double altitude;
} Cache;

#endif
```

this is an example of the output i currently get:

GC13JN5 Penedo de Pena Maior [Braganca] BRAGANCA Bargao_Henriques 41.712433 -6.664450 TRADITIONAL REGULAR 1.5 1.5 AVAILABLE 2007/06/09 32 0 3 654

GC148QM penedo das letras (braga) BRAGA vitinhaxXx 41.467367 -8.457917 MULTI REGULAR 2.0 2.0 AVAILABLE 2007/07/10 157 8 8 442

GCRTEH Monte Redondo LEIRIA mafilll 39.892350 -8.843400 TRADITIONAL SMALL 2.5 3.0 AVAILABLE 2007/04/08 369 17 4 60

Comment: You should read about format specifiers for `printf`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf As an example `"%20s"` would pad the output of the string to a minimum of 20 characters. You could also use `"%*s"` and pass a dynamic width for the field, like if you kept track of the longest item in a particular column and used that to line everything up.

Comment: Note that `%20s` right justifies the data whereas `%-20s` left justifies the data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja awesome reference -- thanks

Comment: Do you need to write your own utility for that? You could just use an existing GNU program: ```column -s ';' -t file.csv```